# $\langle TT\rangle$ correlator of the boundary CFT from metric fluctuations in the bulk gravity

Tags: gravity, string-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, gauss-bonnet

- Is there a reference which explains how the $\langle TT\rangle $ correlation of the boundary conformal field theory (CFT) can be holographically calculated from the bulk gravity? (..I am often getting referred to some paper by Skenderis et. al but I would like to see some more explicit explanation of the idea..)

In the following we defined $C_T$ as the coefficient of the leading singularity of the $\langle TT\rangle $ correlation.

---

Roughly that I understand the following possible algorithm works -

- first expand the gravity Lagrangian about an AdS background making a fluctuation (say $h$ ) along two orthogonal spatial directions of the boundary. Like say add to the metric two off-diagonal components of the type, $g_{xy} = g_{yx} = \epsilon h (r,z)$ where $x,y,z$ are 3 randomly chosen orthogonal spatial directions on the boundary and $r$ is the bulk direction orthogonal to the boundary.
- Now pick out all terms in the Lagrangian which are quadratic in $h$ and focus on all the terms which have a $\partial_r$ and rewrite those terms by pulling out a total derivative in $r$. (...I don't know how to make sense of this if one has terms of the kind $(\partial _r h)(\partial_r ^2 h)$ (and such terms do occur in examples I have tried)
- Now in this "boundary Lagrangian" which is formed by the total derivatives in $r$ and quadratic in $h$ terms substitute a Fourier expansion for $h$ as $h(r,z) = \sum_p e^{ipz}H_p(r)$.
- Now apparently there is (a universal? irrespective of the gravity Lagrangian?) value for this $H$ function which makes the fluctuation go on-shell and for Gauss-Bonnet gravity that apparently is, $H_p(r) = c BesselK[ d/2, (L^2p)/(\sqrt{f_\infty} )]$. And this $c$ is determined by demanding that $H_p (r \rightarrow \infty) = 1$ (where $r=\infty$ is the boundary) [...here its not clear to me as to how will this $f_\infty$ be defined from just the GB Lagrangian - AFAIK this $f_\infty$ is a parameter that is defined only when one is looking for asymptotically $AdS$ blackholes in GB gravity)
- Now expand in a power series in $r$ about $r=\infty$ this boundary Lagrangian and then (for any of its Fourier mode $k$?) for a d-dimensional boundary if the $d$ is even then this $C_T$ is given by the coefficient of the $k^dlog k$ terms and for $d$ odd this is given by the $k^d$ term.

---

- I would like to know if I understand the above algorithm right and if so then what is the reference for its derivation.

Comment: Appendix B.5 in http://qpt.physics.harvard.edu/p234.pdf addresses this derivation. In principle what you are saying is OK, but it is the most non-invariant recipe I have ever seen. One takes the quadratic part of the action, evaluates it on the solutions to linearized equations (propagators). By definition the result is a total derivative, so it resides on the boundary. Careful regularization is needed since the boundary is not a true boundary, so one moves it to the finite distance $\epsilon$ and takes the limit at the end. http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0209067.pdf should be useful.

Comment: @John Thanks for the references! Can you explain what you mean by "evaluates it on the solutions to linearized equations" ? So one has truncated the Lagrangian to second order in fluctuations - now you want to find the equations of motion of the fluctuations for this truncated Lagrangian? (2) Also do you recognize this $H_p$ function that I have quoted? From where does this come? (3) Also how does one define the boundary term corresponding to these quadratic in fluctuation terms? I am not seeing an unambiguous way of doing it

Comment: @John You might want to see this recent paper, 1405.7862 where they have uploaded a Mathematica file called "two_pt_function". In that file you will eventually see this quadrtic in "h" fluctuated Lagrangian written as the function "llag". Now its not clear to me as to how they obtain their boundary Lagrangian (Fourier modes of it) called "bterm" in that Mathematica file. For example they had in "llag" a term of the form, $K_{12}h \partial_r h$ and I don't understand how that in the "bterm" becomes, $-K_{12} (\partial_r H[r,k])H[r,-k]$ (where $K_{12}$ is an arbitrary coefficient)

Comment: @user6818 (h and H are related as stated above)

Comment: (1) I meant the common wisdom that the CFT partition function is an AdS path integral over configurations with presribed boundary conditions (to be identified with the sources to CFT operators). The first approximation is just the classical action evaluated on the solutions and the first approximation to that is quadratic action evaluated on the solutions to the linearized equations. (2) Bessel function is a solution to the boundary problem in AdS, so you just solve $\square_{AdS} \phi=0$. (3) There is a problem with 2-pt functions that the action is not bulk integral but reduces to ...

Comment: the boundary term, so boundary terms bacome important. In principle boundary terms are important when there are boundaries in order to have a well-defined variation problem, see Gibbons-Hawking boundary terms. For AdS CFT the following paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9806216.pdf addresses both questions, boundary terms and stress-tensor two-point function, I think it is the best.

Comment: @John Thanks for your reply! But why should the fluctuation to the metric be a AdS harmonic? One is starting with some arbitrary gravity Lagrangian and truncating it to quadratic order in fluctuations about some background (typically AdS) - then to put the fluctuations on-shell I would have thought that it should satisfy the equations of motion of this truncated Lagramgian? (and that would depend on the details of the Lagrangian chosen) Where am I wrong?

Comment: @John Also what is the logic behind expanding any of the Fourier modes of the quadratic in fluctuations Lagrnagin about the boundary (here $r=\infty$) to get the coefficient of the leading singularity of $<TT>$?

Comment: you take arbitary Lagrangian of gravity+something, the empty AdS is an exact solution. So you can reexpand your action around this solution. Then, one defines propagators, verties as usual. The only point is that the linearized equations are $\square_{AdS}\phi=0$ necessarily, so AdS plane waves are solutions and propagators are of the same form. The details of your Lagrangian are interaction vertices. The last question - it is the AdS/CFT conjecture, and the procedure for getting $<TT>$ this way is a part of it, you can consult any AdS-CFT review

Comment: @John You can see how in 1405.7862 in equations 4.5 and 4.7 the (Fourier modes) quadratically fluctuated Lagrangian and its boundary part is obtained. Now they say this mysterious thing that "...extracting the k^d part of the boundary term when the fluctuations are put on-shell.." somehow gives the coefficient of the leading singularity of the <TT> function. This doesn't make any sense to me. [...further in their attached Mathematica file "two_pt_function" the $H[r,p]$ function that they have defined is NOT the same as the $\phi_k$ function in 4.8 of their paper! (Why!?)..]

Comment: @John Further in the Mathematica file the H[r,p] function seems to be defined for $d=4$ (boundary dimensions) whereas their bulk metric is in 7 dimensions! Why!?

Comment: There is nothing special about this computation, just stress-tensor/graviton have more indices than scalar. For scalar, you can look at appendix A of http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9804058v2.pdf, where it is explained why it is the coefficient of $k^d$ that needs to be looked at (it is the only one surviving actually and gives the right dependence when Fourier transformed back). I cannot help with Mathematica file